# Wpf, при каком DispatcherPriority максимально быстро отрисуются изменения GUI?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new Action(() => OnProgress(this, new ProgressEventArgs(percentage)))
    );
```

С сожалению, нет возможности использовать `BackgroundWorker` или асинхронность.

Хотел бы подобрать такой *DispatcherPriority*, при котором максимально быстро отрисуется GUI. Спасибо!

Имею в планах максимально быстро показать только первое значение `percentage` на прогресс баре. У меня всегда начинается с 1%. Желательно, чтобы это было сразу, синхронно. Затем пусть будет `DispatcherPriority.Background`. Какой тогда должен быть *DispatcherPriority* для первого значения?

Comment: Вы к диспетчеру обращаетесь из какого-то метода, который что-то там обсчитывает?

Comment: Параметр `DispatcherPriority` влияет лишь на то, в какой очерёдности будут выполнены асинхронные операции. Но это не должно влиять на скорость самой отрисовки.

Comment: @VladD на слабой и загруженной машине - визуально вполне может.

Comment: @Monk: Ну, это на очень слабой машине. Я всё же надеюсь, что у ТС машина нормальная, и на ней не всё так грустно.

Answer (score 0):

Есть же [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority(v=vs.110).aspx)

Согласно ему, самый высокий приоритет - `Send`.

Comment: Спасибо, к сожалению, у меня даже Send иногда немного тормозит, что чуть-чуть не красиво.